# Como faço para limitar a movimentação (Touch) de um personagem a 3 pontos específicos? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, touch

Gostaria de saber como faço para limitar a posição de um personagem no eixo Y nas posições Up, Mid, Down. No jogo o personagem corre enquanto surgem obstáculos e arrastando o dedo para cima, se ele estiver na posição "down", ele passa para a posição "Mid", e se estiver na "Mid", pode ir para "up" (arrastando para cima) ou "down" (arrastando para baixo) e assim sucessivamente.Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Sugiro que coloque na pergunta, o codigo do seu script para poder ver onde foi a sua dificuldade e onde terá de alterar coisas. Espero conseguir ajudar!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função Vector3.MoveTowards.
Então, dentro do Update(), você pode usar um if statement para receber o dedo arrastando. Dai você usa o Vector3.MoveTowards para mover o seu object para a posição desejada.
Mais ou menos assim

```
 void Update() {
    if (Swipe pra cima) {
       float step = 3f * Time.deltaTime; //velocidade desejada de movimento.
       Vector3 posiçãoQueVoceQueira = new Vector3(transform.position.x, valorDeterminadoDeY, 0f);
       transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, posiçãoQueVoceQueira, step);
    }
}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado!